# How to get the REMOTE_USER variable with PHP under linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache-modules

I've already searched for this problem but i didn't find a working solution. May you could help.

I have to get with PHP the **REMOTE_USER** from the loggend in User in the company **Domain**, so his username in the intranet. The REMOTE_IP an so on is all set, but the REMOTE_USER, which we use for authentications on our intranet applications can is not transmitted.

The Server Setup is as following:

- ServerOS: RedHat
- PHP: 5.6.15
- Apache: 2.2.31
- OpenSSL: 1.0.2
- The server has **NO** internet connection and yum install isn't working because of security reasons. The only thing I can do is download, make install and compile things with gcc.

I do not need an strong authentication or something like that, I only need the remote's username.

I hope you can help.

Thank you very much for your help and advices

Greetings
Stefan

Comment: A side note: I still would consider it a better practice to install pre built packages instead of self compiling everything. You don't need a direct internet connection for that. You can upload the packages. You just have to take care to retrieve them from a safe location, but that obviously applies just as well to retrieval of the source code to build own packages.